# Why are the animation rotation value in Maya different from that in Unity?

Tags: python, animation, rotation, unity-game-engine, maya

I have a FBX file with animation in it. When I import it into Maya(2017), the rotation value of bone 'arm_r_shoulder' looks like this:

[image: maya Image]

But the value just changed after importing it into Unity(5.6.1f1):

[image: Unity Image]

The fbx can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9P3vNPjen5dOTEwZ3NhZXIzTGs).

My question is, why are those values different? And how should I handle that?

Comment: Would you be able to show a screenshot of Rotate Axis and Joint Orient Values in maya? Its in the attribute editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it's the `Rotate Order` and/or `Order of Transformation` issues. At first, check what `Rotate Order` in Maya and then in Unity. This parameter must be the same in both packages.

[image]

You can change the `Rotate Order` but preserve the overall transformation in Maya using this line of code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.xform(preserve=True, rotateOrder='yzx')
```

Also, there's Euler rotation vs Quaternion Rotation scheme:
[image]

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.rotationInterpolation('polyModel_rotateY', convert='quaternion')
```

Read this post to know how to make conversions using Python: [Quaternion to Euler Rotations](http://discourse.techart.online/t/quaternion-to-euler-rotations/5076).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your method and there seems to be something wrong with the y value. I've created some joints and set the rotate order to zxy, the value seems to be (-14.790, 106.457, -94.312), but after importing it to unity, the value became (-14.79, 30.179, 94.312).

Comment: Check the method: Euler or Quaternion.

Comment: Where can I modify the method please? In the export config or...?

Comment: Preferences - Animation - Rotation Interpolation.

Comment: Graph Editor - Curves - Change Rotation Interp.